# passing objects from Fragment A to Fragment B, then to Fragment C and then back to Fragment A

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am a newbie in android programing. I have this problem , hope you can spare time to help me.:)

I have a a **fragment (A)** ,in which there is a button. When I click this button, it will pop up a **dialog (B)** with 2 buttons : *modify-date-button* and *modify-time-button*. Click on each of these buttons will lead to DatePicker **dialog (C)** and TimePicker dialog (C) correspondingly. The TimePicker and DatePicker will be initialized with the time *sent from fragment A*. Then in DatePicker/TimePicker dialog, users can modify the date/time and the date/time change will be shown in fragment A.

Please note that, I put fragment A in an activity; dialog B in a fragment; dialog C in a fragment.

I don't know what is the best way to pass data from A to C , and then C back to A (with B in the middle).

I learn that we can use *Fragment.setTargetFragment()* and *Fragment.getTargetFragment().onActivityResult()* to send data from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and then back to fragment 1. But here, the situation is that I have 3 fragments. I don't know what is the best practice for this.

Thank you for your reading . If you find my explanation is not clear , please ask me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can perhaps look into using an interface between the fragments you want to pass the data between. and the TargetFragment idea is not a bad one just pass Fragment A as the target fragment to Fragment B then to Fragment C.

Comment: Many thanks! I will look into the use of interface between the fragments I want to pass data. That is a better idea than pass from A  --> B --> C   and then back from C --> B --> A. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dialog C closes, pass the date/time back to B. When B receives the date/time, immediately close B and pass the date/time back to A.